# How to password protect a saved Excel file from a bat file(or other script)?

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to protect an Excel file (using vba's `Workbook.Protect` for example) with a given path and run it from a bat script or other script file?

I couldn't find a way to run the commands from a saved script file

Answer (score 2):

This is [VBScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//0ad0dkea(v=vs.85)), expects to be called with a command line parameter being the path to the Excel Workbook file that is to be protected.

It assumes the Excel Workbook to be protected is not already open.

See comments in code for an explanation.

```
Option Explicit

' Check we have 1 command line parameter
If WScript.Arguments.Count <> 1 Then
    MsgBox "Expected one parameter (a filename) - received: " & WScript.Arguments.Count, vbInformation
    WScript.Quit
End If

' Get the parameter and check if it is an existing file
Dim pathToFile, fso
pathToFile = Wscript.Arguments(0)
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If (fso.FileExists(pathToFile)) Then
    ' nothing
Else
    MsgBox "Not a valid file: " & pathToFile, vbInformation
    WScript.Quit    
End If

' Check it ends '.xlsx'
If (Len(pathToFile) < 5) Then
    MsgBox "Not an Excel Workbook: " & pathToFile, vbInformation
    WScript.Quit    
End If
If (Right(pathToFile, 5) <> ".xlsx") Then ' or also test for .xlsm, .xls etc per your needs
    MsgBox "Not an Excel Workbook: " & pathToFile, vbInformation
    WScript.Quit    
End If

' start Excel, get Workbook, protect it
Dim oExcel, oWkb
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set oWkb = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(pathToFile)
If oWkb.ProtectStructure Then
    MsgBox "Workbook is already protected", vbInformation
Else
    oWkb.Protect "MyPassword1234" ' use your password ... protect structure if desired
    MsgBox "Protected!", vbInformation
End If

' save, close, exit
oWkb.Save
oWkb.Close
oExcel.Quit
```

Save as a .vbs file. To demo it, create a shortcut to that .vbs file. Open the Properties for that shortcut (ie right click it and select Properties), in the Target field, append a space and the path to the Excel workbook file (in speech marks if any spaces in the path). Apply and close the Properties.

Double click the shortcut.

> EDIT ... see comment below, this version password-protects opening of the Excel Workbook file.

Again this assumes the Excel Workbook to be password-protected is not already open plus assumes the Excel Workbook to be password-protected is not already password-protected!

See comments in code for an explanation.

```
Option Explicit

' Check we have 1 command line parameter
If WScript.Arguments.Count <> 1 Then
    MsgBox "Expected one parameter (a filename) - received: " & WScript.Arguments.Count, vbInformation
    WScript.Quit
End If

' Get the parameter and check if it is an existing file
Dim pathToFile, fso
pathToFile = Wscript.Arguments(0)
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If (fso.FileExists(pathToFile)) Then
    ' nothing
Else
    MsgBox "Not a valid file: " & pathToFile, vbInformation
    WScript.Quit    
End If

' Check it ends '.xlsx'
If (Len(pathToFile) < 5) Then
    MsgBox "Not an Excel Workbook: " & pathToFile, vbInformation
    WScript.Quit    
End If
If (Right(pathToFile, 5) <> ".xlsx") Then ' or also text for .xlsm, .xls etc per your needs
    MsgBox "Not an Excel Workbook: " & pathToFile, vbInformation
    WScript.Quit    
End If

' start Excel, get Workbook, protect it
Dim oExcel, oWkb
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set oWkb = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(pathToFile)
oWkb.Password = "MyPassword1234"
MsgBox "Protected!", vbInformation

' save, close, exit
oWkb.Save
oWkb.Close
oExcel.Quit
```

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to run this file from CMD with the file name as the input instead of via properties? Something like `excel_password_protect.vbs "C:/path/to/excel.xlsx"`?

Comment: Update: I just tried, and it acts weird: When I run the script it says "Protected!", but the xlsx is not protected and I can open the file. But when I run the script again it says "Workbook is already protected" even though it's not, but it does detect it as protected

Comment: On your first comment ... yes, you can do exactly that ... just as you typed ... the VBScript needs no changes for that. On your second comment, the script executes the [Workbook.Protect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.protect) Excel function (as per your question) ... this protects the Workbook from certain types of modification - if you open the Workbook in Excel and look in the Review tab, you will see the 'Protect Workbook' button is 'pressed in' and if you click it you can un-protect the Workbook.

Comment: Thank you, I was just sure that protecting a workbook means that you won't be able to open the file at all (I know you can have a prompt when opening an Excel file before you even see anything inside, is it possible as well?)

Comment: See updated VBScript which password-protects the Excel Workbook file which I think is, them, what you are wanting